# jQuery Autocomplete - without any styling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the jQuery Autocomplete code which displays result with some styling
.How to remove all the styling properties so that it looks like raw html dropdown ? If it is not possible is it possible to create the same autocomplete effect in pure javascript?

**Existing Code :**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  function sendvalues()
  {
  alert();
  }
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
   
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
  sendvalues();
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );
 
  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
  
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
 
  <select id="combobox" onchange="sendvalues()">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="kkk">kkk</option>
    <option value="sd">asf</option>
 <option value="abdfac">abasdfsac</option>
    <option value="kgfjkgkk">kkyk</option>
    <option value="sghkd">asgyjf</option>
 <option value="abyuic">abftfjvhjc</option>
    <option value="kkkgyjhk">kkgjk</option>
    <option value="sml,hud">asnjmf</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

When i just removed the css import the entire functionality changes. The value gets displayed below the combobox in list and selected value gets displayed separetely and there is no downward arrow.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  function sendvalues()
  {
  alert();
  }
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
   
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
  sendvalues();
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );
 
  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
  
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
 
  <select id="combobox" onchange="sendvalues()">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="kkk">kkk</option>
    <option value="sd">asf</option>
 <option value="abdfac">abasdfsac</option>
    <option value="kgfjkgkk">kkyk</option>
    <option value="sghkd">asgyjf</option>
 <option value="abyuic">abftfjvhjc</option>
    <option value="kkkgyjhk">kkgjk</option>
    <option value="sml,hud">asnjmf</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the CSS tied to the select

Comment: could you use an html5 datalist?

Comment: You could also just not import the css

Comment: I can answer your second part of your question - 'If it is not possible is it possible to create the same autocomplete effect in pure javascript?' Whatever is possible with jQuery, It is surely possible with JavaScript!

Comment: @all Please see the updated question.

Comment: @daniel : cross-browser support is also important so cannot use datalist. But what i am looking for is exactly similar to dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below styling properties resolved the issue.

```
 <style>
      .custom-combobox {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .custom-combobox-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        height:17px;
        background:transparent;
        border-radius:0px;
      }
      .custom-combobox-input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        width:150px;height:17px;
        background:transparent;
        border-radius:0px;
      }
      .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px 0em 0px 0em;
        cursor: pointer;
        min-height: 0;
     background:transparent;
    }
      </style>
```

**Final Code :**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
 height:17px;
 background:transparent;
 border-radius:0px;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
 width:150px;height:17px;
 background:transparent;
 border-radius:0px;
  }
  .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0em 0px 0em;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 0;
 background:transparent;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  function sendvalues()
  {
  alert();
  }
  function combo()
 {
 alert();
  $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
 }
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
   
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
  sendvalues();
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( ".combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
function loada()
{
document.getElementById("two").innerHTML=document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
}
</script>
<div id="one">


  <select class="combobox" id="one" onchange="sendvalues()" onload="combo()">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="kkk">kkk</option>
    <option value="sd">asf</option>
 <option value="abdfac">abasdfsac</option>
    <option value="kgfjkgkk">kkyk</option>
    <option value="sghkd">asgyjf</option>
 <option value="abyuic">abftfjvhjc</option>
    <option value="kkkgyjhk">kkgjk</option>
    <option value="sml,hud">asnjmf</option>
    
  </select>
   </div>

 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "remove all the styling so that it looks like a raw html dropdown". You have to *add*, or modify, styling to make it look the way you want.

The reason it doesn't look right when you remove the CSS is that you're using a complex plugin for complex behavior. If you remove any part of the plugin (especially a big part like the CSS) the whole "machine" is going to break.

What you need to do is add some styles of your own to override the plugin's style, or alter the style that the plugin uses.

It looks to me as though the biggest difference between the way this looks and the way a "natural" autocomplete box looks is that this box has that light grey background gradient. If you right click that element and select "inspect element" you'll see all the CSS rules that affect it. You just need to find the rule that causes it to have that background.

In this case it appears that any element with the class `ui-state-default` is meant to have the background image `images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png`, and that rule is from jquery-ui.css, at line 866. So you can either find that css rule and modify it to suit your needs or you can introduce a style sheet of your own and override this style.

Then keep following that procedure for each little change you need to make: inspect element; find the rule that styles it so; change or override the rule. (I would recommend overriding rather than changing on general principle, to make it less likely that you break the plugin)

Hope this helps. Comment or edit your post if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JsFiddle :  [https://jsfiddle.net/kd57ebj7/][1]
```

With your html with some css.